# Open current chrome tab with a different profile

Tags: google-chrome, productivity

On Chrome I use several profiles to manage my personal and work life.
There is one handy option to open a link to a page with a different profile. You just right click on the link and then select open as and then you selects the other profile. 
This is neat, but it useless when you already have the tab opened.
What I want to do is open the current tab with a different profile.
Is that possible with just chrome? Is there any extension that can be used for this purpose?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 8):

You can drag the  lock symbol from the left of the address bar, to drop the current page’s URL onto a different (profile’s) window’s tab bar or address bar (or bookmarks bar).

If the target window(’s tab bar) is not in view, you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the window while dragging, or drag (and not drop yet) onto its button in the task bar to bring the window to the foreground.

(If you are lost among many open windows, you can select a target profile, to bring its last focused window to the foreground, by clicking on the current profile’s pic in the top right area of the Chrome window.)

Comment: The dragging turns out to be very difficult to perform in case two browser windows opened in a full screen mode. It takes two hands to switch between workspaces, but one hand is "busy" holding the link in a dragged state. I'm still not sure how to manage this case. Alt-tab is useless because it does not include multiple windows from the same application.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not averse to using a different browser, Firefox has a nifty feature where you can have container tabs. Each container is isolated from the other.

You can have a maximum of 9 + 1 containers, but if you are separating only work and personal stuff you can configure 2 containers.
And it's easy to open a link or any tab in a different container. Just right click the tab or link and select open in container > and select the appropriate container

[image: screenshot of switching containers]

I use container tabs on my work profile because I have to test multiple user logins and container tabs have made it so easy to have multiple sessions on the same browser window

Edit: almost forgot, you will need to install Mozilla's extension called [multi account containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers).

Comment: I am not adverse against it, but the original reason why I want to open it with a different chrome profile is because I sync it with my mobile and other devices and it becomes easier for me to account for all my tabs open across devices, therefore I am able to read it later without effort. I sometimes use firefox, but only for testing purposes. I tried their sync feature when it was release and it was super basic and not easy to use, so I never tried again, maybe it's time to give it another look

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found so far:
For multiple tabs, although I agree it's not the fastest way. Only if you use it once/ occasionally:

- Go to ... (three vertical dots button at the top right corner)
- Chose Bookmarks -> Bookmark all tabs (or default short cut: Ctrl+Shift+D)
- Give it a new folder name
- Then go to Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager
- Find your just saved folder
- At the top right corner click three vertical dots
- Click "Export Bookmarks"
- Give a file a name
- In the other profile again go to Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager
- At the top right corner click three vertical dots
- Click "Import Bookmarks"
- Select the file with your bookmarks
- The folder will appear on the left
- Select the folder, right click and select "Open All"

Now you'll have all your tabs in the new profile. Although the autocomplete/passwords will not be saved this way...

- As for the single tab, I'd just copy paste the link from one profile to another.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to quickly accomplish this using the Session Buddy extension. You will need to use the Export/Import function to transfer between profiles. If you just use Save, you won't be able to see the saved session from the other profile.

- Install the Session Buddy extension in both Chrome instances.
- Open up SB in the profile instance that has the open tabs you want to transfer.
- If you have a lot of tabs open and only want to transfer a few, save your current session (so you can restore it after the transfer) and then close all the tabs you don't want to transfer. You could transfer everything, but it can take a very long time to reload all those tabs if you have a gazillion.
- Click on the Settings (Gear) icon to find the Export option. Save the URLs to a text file.
- Go to SB in the new profile and click on Import under the Settings icon. Open the file you just saved and voila, there are your tabs opened in the new profile instance.
- Restore your saved session in the original profile if you closed a bunch of tabs before exporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-open other profiles and whenever you need to open a link in another profile just select and drag the link into other profile's new tab area.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The OP already knows how to open new links in another profile. They are specifically asking how to move an *already opened tab* to another profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about speed, then the suggestion to "drag the  lock symbol from the left of the address bar onto a different (profile’s) window’s tab bar or address bar" is a good one.

If you're looking for a way to do this using the keyboard on a Mac, you can use an Applescript that is activated using a hotkey (e.g. BetterTouchTool).

```
-- copy current URL to clipboard
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set the clipboard to URL of active tab of front window as text
end tell

-- delays necessary, especially when switching windows
delay 0.1

tell application "System Events"
    -- make sure commands are being told to "Google Chrome"
    tell (name of first application process whose frontmost is true)
        -- switch to other profile (assuming only 2)
        keystroke "m" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 0.1
        keystroke return
        delay 0.2
        -- open a new tab
        keystroke "t" using {command down}
        delay 0.2
        -- paste the URL from the clipboard
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        delay 0.1
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Connect this Applescript to a keyboard command, and then use it whenever you want to copy the current page to another profile. Note: I'm assuming you only have 2 profiles. If you have more, then additional logic will be required to select the correct profile after pressing `Command+Shift+M`.

Answer (score 0):

Edge has this functionality, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image: Edge screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

My idea is also through bookmarks, but a little different and easier. Just copy and paste.

1. Save all bookmarks with
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in a folder with a
   name of your choice
2. Then go to bookmark management and the desired folder
   Now select all desired bookmarks and copy them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Go to your other Chrome profile
4. Go to Manage Bookmarks
5. You can create a folder and paste the bookmarks there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Opening links except in Chrome tabs mode when it is a link on the same page:
Right clicking and selecting another profile is possible when the links are on the same page.

Like the links we have from Google search, we can right-click on them and select the desired profile from open link to open it there, of course, it is individually, if we want to open these links in a group, we can use the plugin like [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en).

Comment: Welcome to SU, and thanks or your contribution. Unfortunately it's not helpful. The OP knows how to open a link with a new profile: _"There is one handy option to open a link to a page with a different profile. You just right click on the link and then select open as and then you selects the other profile. "_ Their question is how to reopen the _current_ open tab with a new profile, and that you're not answering. I'd suggest deleting this as it doesn't answer the question.